Performance drop when updating shader node field variables in large scenes through python script
for a project I’m working on, I am importing a large number of objects (on the order of 100,000 objects) and creating variations of the same material for each.
However, I noticed that the import times are not linear to the amount of objects imported as I expected. To my surprise, the biggest contributor to the increased time is changing a field in the material. I created a minimal example to demonstrate this issue, which you can find here.
Alternatively, this is a screenshot of the relevant part of the scene:

In the minimal example, if you run the script with the system console visible, you can observe the time it takes to change the field variable 1000 times. As more materials and shader-nodes are created, the time it takes to complete the same number of field variable changes increases significantly.(Node selection etc. is not timed, as that is expected to increase.)
I expected that setting a variable can be performed in continuous time, but instead the performance seems to be affected with each new material created.
I am using Blender 4.1.1 on Windows 10. Is there a known workaround or method to reduce this effect, or is this just a limitation I will have to work around?
Thanks for your help!
